# Copying content of one table's attribute to another table's attribute in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model-view-controller

I'm a beginner in the rails development and I am currently working on enhancements on a marketplace already implemented and I am stuck.

I wanted to modify the code in order to copy the content of a table's attribute which is named "custom_field_values" in another attribute of another table which is named "listings".

I wrote this code in the custom_field_value model:

```
  before_validation :set_date_value
  def set_date_value
    @current_listing = Listing.where(id: listing_id).select(:valid_until) 
    @current_listing= date_value
  end
```

but something went wrong because the table value receive Null and not the content itself.
I tried also to use the listing_controller to join the two tables and assign the value but nothing happens and I am still getting a Null value.

By the way here is the two table schema :

## Table name: custom_field_values

```
  id              :integer          not null, primary key
  custom_field_id :integer
  listing_id      :integer
  text_value      :text(65535)
  numeric_value   :float(24)
  date_value      :datetime
  created_at      :datetime         not null
  updated_at      :datetime         not null
  type            :string(255)
```

## Table name: listings

```
  id                              :integer          not null, primary key
  uuid                            :binary(16)       not null
  community_id                    :integer          not null
  author_id                       :string(255)
  category_old                    :string(255)
  title                           :string(255)
  times_viewed                    :integer          default(0)
  language                        :string(255)
  created_at                      :datetime
  updates_email_at                :datetime
  updated_at                      :datetime
  last_modified                   :datetime
  sort_date                       :datetime
  listing_type_old                :string(255)
  description                     :text(65535)
  origin                          :string(255)
  destination                     :string(255)
  valid_until                     :datetime
  delta                           :boolean          default(TRUE), not null
  open                            :boolean          default(TRUE)
  share_type_old                  :string(255)
  privacy                         :string(255)      default("private")
  comments_count                  :integer          default(0)
  subcategory_old                 :string(255)
  old_category_id                 :integer
  category_id                     :integer
  share_type_id                   :integer
  listing_shape_id                :integer
  transaction_process_id          :integer
  shape_name_tr_key               :string(255)
  action_button_tr_key            :string(255)
  price_cents                     :integer
  currency                        :string(255)
  quantity                        :string(255)
  unit_type                       :string(32)
  quantity_selector               :string(32)
  unit_tr_key                     :string(64)
  unit_selector_tr_key            :string(64)
  deleted                         :boolean          default(FALSE)
  require_shipping_address        :boolean          default(FALSE)
  pickup_enabled                  :boolean          default(FALSE)
  shipping_price_cents            :integer
  shipping_price_additional_cents :integer
  availability                    :string(32)       default("none")
```

Comment: I understand your problem. But can you expose more of your model's code so I can give you the best possible answer?
For now, you can write 
`@current_listing = Listing.where(id: listing_id).select(:valid_until) `  
`@current_listing.date_value = date_value`  
`@current_listing.save`

Answer (score 0):

here is the correction, use find instead of where to find one record, where will return collection of record, and to access column field inside a model use self

```
before_validation :set_date_value
def set_date_value
  @current_listing = Listing.find_by(id: self.listing_id)
  # if find successfully (not nil)
  if @current_listing 
    @current_listing.valid_until = self.date_value
  end
end
```

Comment: If the listing is not found with `Listing.find`, the code will throw an ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound Error. So no use of checking `if @current_listing`. You can do `Listing.find_by(id: self.listing_id)` then check for @current_listing.

Comment: find_by_id works fine but is deprecated in favor of more flexible syntax which is like find_by(id: some_id). Cheers.

Comment: Thank you for this solution, but I used it and I am getting the Null value in the valid_date . I tried to pass a static value from the other custom_field_value model to the listings table and still the Null value .

Comment: how about if you change before_validation to before_save

Comment: @widjajayd I changed it to before_save but it dosen't change the output.

Comment: ok then it seems date_value field from  custom_field_values is null, you should check it from rails console and make sure it record has value for example, run rails console , and then check first values a = CustomFieldValue.first and then type a.date_value

Answer (score 0):

My solution is that you should use listings association rather than query for `Listing` separately and using instance variable to hold it.

```
def set_date_value
  listing.valid_until = date_value if listing
end
```

this will use the `belongs_to :listing` association to set the valid_until column and is more concise.

Comment: Thank you for this solution, but I used it and I am getting the Null value in the valid_date . I tried to pass a static value from the other custom_field_value model to the listings table and still the Null value .

Comment: There must be some problem in your model if you're getting Nil. Can provide some more information, maybe show a bit more of your model code. How are you accessing the value?

Comment: I can help you over a short Skype session

Comment: Could we please have a hangout conversation instead of skype this is my email address : yasserkotrsi@gmail.com
Thnx a lot.